# Phantom.js stuck on choosing next element

Tags: javascript, automation, phantomjs

I'm trying to use Phantom.JS to do some page automation on this page: https://reserve.apple.com/GB/en_GB/reserve/iPhone

I know how to use `document.getElementById('store') = "R363"` to choose the first option. But it seems after I've chosen the first option, the DOM element of the original page will change and I don't know how to achieve that using Phantom.JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `document.getElementById('store') = "R363"` try using jQuery instead like so:

```
var page = require('webpage').create(); 
// open the page
page.open('https://reserve.apple.com/GB/en_GB/reserve/iPhone', function() {
    //inject jQuery
    page.includeJs("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js", function() {
        // run the following code in the context of the page
        page.evaluate(function() {
            // change the value of the combobox
            $("#store").val( newval );

            // do stuff in the page
        });
        phantom.exit()
    });
});
```